# Understanding minizinc

Tags: minizinc

The exercise is:

A group of n people wants to take a group photo. Each person can give preferences next to whom he or she
wants to be placed on the photo. The problem to be solved is to find a placement that satisfies maximum number
of preferences.

The code I have written so far:

```
include "globals.mzn";

% input variables
int: n;
int: n_prefs;
array[1..n_prefs, 1..2] of var 1..n: prefs;

% FDV:s
array [1..n] of var 1..n: photo_arrangement;
var 0..n_prefs: cost;

constraint
     all_different(photo_arrangement)
% MORE Constraints

solve maximize cost;

output [show( photo_arrangement )]
```

n is the number of persons in the photo

n_prefs is the number of preferences

prefs is the matrix containing all the preferences

The main idea is to have a an array containing the persons 1 to n, and a cost variable that we want to maximize. 
How can I change the cost variable depending on the preferences?

Comment: How are your preferences encoded? Why are preferences declared as `var 1..n`, when they should be an input to the formula, according to the description? does `n_prefs` forbid symmetric preferences, e.g. `1,2` and `2,1`? does `n_prefs` forbid reflexive preferences, .e.g. `1,1`? does `n_prefs` forbid duplicates? Are these constraints already *guaranteed* or should one check them at *runtime*?

Comment: Well one example input for prefs is:

prefs = [| 1,3 | 1,5 | 1,8 | 2,5 | 2,9 |
        3,4 | 3,5 | 4,1 | 4,5 | 5,6 | 5,1 |
        6,1 | 6,9 | 7,3 | 7,8 | 8,9 | 8,7 |];

So maybe the input declaration of prefs is wrong. Should maybe be more simple, like this: 

array [int, int] of int: prefs ?

Comment: The prefs input is a matrix with n_refs rows and two columns holding the preference. [| 1,3 | ... means person 1 wants to have person 3 next besides him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one approach. (Update: Actually, here are now three different models with the same underlying idea.)

```
include "globals.mzn";

% input variables
int: n;
int: n_prefs;
array[1..n_prefs, 1..2] of 1..n: prefs;

% FDV:s
array [1..n] of var 1..n: photo_arrangement;
% the positions of each person in photo_arrangement
array [1..n] of var 1..n: pa_inv = inverse(photo_arrangement); 
% to see what preferences that are satisfied
array[1..n_prefs] of var int: prefs_sat; 
var 0..n_prefs: cost;

constraint
  all_different(photo_arrangement)
  /\
  forall(p in 1..n_prefs) (
     % note: we use the inverse of photo_arrangement for indexing since we
     %       want to compare the positions of the two persons prefs[p,1] and prefs[p,2]
    prefs_sat[p] = if abs(pa_inv[prefs[p,1]]-pa_inv[prefs[p,2]]) = 1 then 1 else 0 endif
 )
 /\
 cost = sum(prefs_sat)
 ;

 solve :: int_search(photo_arrangement, first_fail, indomain_split, complete) maximize cost;
 output [
   "cost: \(cost)\nphoto_arrangement: \(photo_arrangement)\n(pa_inv:           \(pa_inv))\n"
 ] ++
 [
   show([prefs[p,i] | i in 1..2]) ++ ": " ++ show(prefs_sat[p]) ++ "\n"
   | p in 1..n_prefs
 ];

 % data
 n = 9;
 n_prefs = 17;
 prefs = [| 1,3 | 1,5 | 1,8 | 2,5 | 2,9 | 3,4 | 3,5 | 4,1 | 4,5 | 5,6 | 5,1 | 6,1 | 6,9 | 7,3 | 7,8 | 8,9 | 8,7 |];
```

The main point is the use of an extra array (`pa_inv`) which is the `inverse` of `photo_arrangement` and shows the position for each person. This means that we can use `pa_inv[1]` to get the position of person 1, and thus can calculate the difference of the positions of `pa_inv[prefs[p,1]` and `pa_inv[prefs[p,2]` (which is 1 if the two persons is between each other). The `prefs_sat` array shows if a preference is satisfied (1) or not (0).

There are 20 optimal solutions with 10 satisfied preferences. One optimal solutions is:

```
cost: 10
photo_arrangement: [2, 5, 1, 4, 3, 7, 8, 9, 6]
(pa_inv:           [3, 1, 5, 4, 2, 9, 6, 7, 8])
[1, 3]: 0
[1, 5]: 1
[1, 8]: 0
[2, 5]: 1
[2, 9]: 0
[3, 4]: 1
[3, 5]: 0
[4, 1]: 1
[4, 5]: 0
[5, 6]: 0
[5, 1]: 1
[6, 1]: 0
[6, 9]: 1
[7, 3]: 1
[7, 8]: 1
[8, 9]: 1
[8, 7]: 1
```

**Update some minutes later:**

Here is another approach using the `element` function instead of using `inverse`, which means that we don't need the `pa_inv` array. The `forall` loop in the code above can be replaced with:

```
  %  
  forall(p in 1..n_prefs) (
       prefs_sat[p] = if abs(element([prefs[p,1],photo_arrangement)-element(prefs[p,2],photo_arrangement)) = 1 then 1 else 0 endif
   )
  %
```

**Update some days later:**
There is another - and arguably simpler - model, similar to the previous approaches, but it use the "inverse" part in the output instead.

```
include "globals.mzn";
int: n;
int: n_prefs;
array[1..n_prefs, 1..2] of 1..n: prefs;
array [1..n] of var 1..n: photo_arrangement;
var 0..n_prefs: cost;

constraint
   all_different(photo_arrangement) /\
   cost = sum(p in 1..n_prefs) (
      if abs(photo_arrangement[prefs[p,1]]-photo_arrangement[prefs[p,2]]) = 1 then 1 else 0 endif
          )
;

solve :: int_search(photo_arrangement, first_fail, indomain_split, complete) maximize cost;

output [
   "cost: \(cost)\nphoto_arrangement: \(photo_arrangement)\n",
  "positions:\n"
] ++ [
   if fix(photo_arrangement[j]) = i then show(j) ++ " " else "" endif
  | i,j in 1..n
];

n = 9;
n_prefs = 17;
prefs = [| 1,3 | 1,5 | 1,8 | 2,5 | 2,9 | 3,4 | 3,5 | 4,1 | 4,5 | 5,6 | 5,1 | 6,1 | 6,9 | 7,3 | 7,8 | 8,9 | 8,7 |];
```

The solution is

```
cost: 10
photo_arrangement: [8, 1, 5, 6, 7, 9, 4, 3, 2]
positions:
2 9 8 7 3 4 5 1 6
```